# Why do websites tend to show the content to the left?

Tags: composition, content

I've noticed a trend in content positioning on popular websites such as facebook, youtube, 9gag and many more.. they all have their main content to the left side of website. Why is this? Or is it just random?

Comment: That is an interesting thing to notice . . . I think ever since the beginning development of the web, the left hand side, or the upper left hand corner, has been considered the anchor point. Even in desktop applications this is the case. For example, people have grown accustomed to having their menus on the left, and ones on the right now seem oddly out of place.

Comment: English speakers start on the left and move tot he right. Important content is always on the upper left side of any English-speaking layout.

Comment: It is what Scott said and also considered the "F Pattern" which we have an existing question about that I think answers your question: [Should the F-Pattern be considered in all designs?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6334/should-the-f-pattern-be-considered-in-all-designs)